# Bigquery DATABRICKS CONNECTIVITY

Tags: google-bigquery, databricks, aws-databricks

How to access data from Big Query to dataframe in databricks using credentials in secrets.

```
df = spark
    .read
    .format("bigquery")
    .option("credentialsFile",credentialfilepath)
    .option("parentProject",projectName)
    .option("table",table).load()
```

Used above but since i am passing the account details of GCP from secrets not sure on how to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#how-do-i-authenticate-outside-gce--dataproc) on this say:

> Credentials can also be provided explicitly, either as a parameter or from Spark runtime configuration. They should be passed in as a base64-encoded string directly.
>
> ```
> // Globally
> spark.conf.set("credentials", "<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_IN_BASE64>")
> // Per read/Write
> spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentials", "<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_IN_BASE64>")
> ```

Assuming you have your access details in Databricks secret scope, you just read it from there using [dbutils](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#secrets-utility-dbutilssecrets):

```
df = spark
    .read
    .format("bigquery")
    .option("credentials",dbutils.secrets.get("<scope>", "<secret>"))
    .option("parentProject",projectName)
    .option("table",table).load()
```